# How can I get more power out from a windmill motor?

Tags: stepper-motor, wind-power, current, electronics

As far my knowledge a dynamo is a motor which provides electricity when the rotor shaft is rotated. My Question to be brief is if I connect multiple dynamos in a single shaft will I get more current? Will the current be in AC or DC? What will happen if I replace dynamos with 12 volt DC motors? Will the current output (Ampere) be higher or the Voltage?

Comment: The power output is limited by the power input and the losses.

Comment: so how is that a commercial wind power plant can yield Terra watts of power? Is there any way to get out more juice out of a single windmill?

Comment: Because they have multiple wind turbines each producing power from different parts of the airstream ie wind. Back to power out = power in minus losses...

Comment: Don’t keep changing your comments.

Comment: With wind generators, size matters.  Large wind turbine driving large generator = MW of power.

Answer (score 1):

> As far my knowledge a dynamo is a motor which provides electricity when the rotor shaft is rotated.

A dynamo will give DC output. An alternator will give AC output.

> If I connect multiple dynamos in a single shaft will I get more current?

Yes, if the mechanical drive continues to run at the same speed. Adding electrical load will add mechanical load to the mill.

> Will the current be in AC or DC?

Dynamos and alternators.

> What will happen if I replace dynamos with 12 volt DC motors?

Brushed DC motors and brushed dynamos are pretty much the same thing. A motor can be used as a dynamo.

> Will the current output (Ampere) be higher or the Voltage?

Connecting dynamos of the same type in parallel will increase the output current provided the shaft speed is maintained.